# Netbeans 8.1, Gluon Project Android Error

Tags: android, netbeans, javafx, javafxports, gluon

I'm using Netbeans 8.1, with gluon and nbandroid plugins, on Windows 8.1, and when I create a gluon basic project i can't run on Android platform, the error are about `ANDROID_HOME`, in the last two days I have searched a lot about it but all the tries I have made don't help.

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: ANDROID_HOME not specified. Either set it as a gradle property, a system environment variable or directly in your build.gradle by setting the extension jfxmobile.android.androidSdk.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: ANDROID_HOME not specified. Either set it as a gradle property, a system environment variable or directly in your build.gradle by setting the extension jfxmobile.android.androidSdk.
```

I tried the sample project from gluon, and the error still appears, but if I create an Android project (nbandroid, not gluon) and run it, everything is ok.

I see same difference from other questions on the project, when I create a gluon basic project automatically a Android project is created, but i don't see that on a lot of movies i watch on Youtube.

[image: When create project GluonApplicationtest automatically apear android]

Can anyone help me, please? If more data is needed, I can upload it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a look at the JavaFXPorts [documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#anchor-1) on the prerequisites to get started.

There are several options on how to set `ANDROID_HOME`. Basically:

Define the `androidSdk` property under jfxmobile.android in build.gradle:

```
jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = 'C:/<path to>/Android/sdk'
    }
}
```

Or create a file named `grade.properties`, and place it in your local gradle folder (`C:/Users/<user>/.gradle`), adding this property:

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:/<path to>/Android/sdk
```

If you use the second option, you won't need to take care of adding it all the time on new projects.

Also you will find this local file added on your NetBeans projects, in a `Gradle Home` folder:

[image: gradle]